# Horizontal SingleChildScrollView not working inside a Column on Windows

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-windows

Updated: Thanks for all the replies. Check again. It's only not working on windows. android and macos work fine.

---

I cannot scroll the row. I've set Column.crossAxisAlignment to `stretch` and `SingleChildScrollView.scrollDirection` to horizontal. What am I missing?

```dart
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: Row(children: [
              Text(' lis sdf sd fsd fsdf ifje fsiduhf iushdf sdf '),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Text(' lis sdf sd fsd fsdf ifje fsiduhf iushdf sdf ')),
              Text(' lis sdf sd fsd fsdf ifje fsiduhf iushdf sdf ')
            ]),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

[image]

Comment: Everything is just working fine. Can you recheck the post

Comment: Hi, checked again. it's working on macos and android, not on windows :D

Answer (score 3):

> [ScrollBehaviors](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/default-desktop-scrollbars) now allow or disallow drag scrolling from specified PointerDeviceKinds. ScrollBehavior.dragDevices, by default, allows scrolling widgets to be dragged by all PointerDeviceKinds except for PointerDeviceKind.mouse.

To enable touch scroll extend `MaterialScrollBehavior`  and provide on `MaterialApp`.

```dart
class MyCustomScrollBehavior extends MaterialScrollBehavior {
  // Override behavior methods like buildOverscrollIndicator and buildScrollbar
  @override
  Set<PointerDeviceKind> get dragDevices => {
        PointerDeviceKind.touch,
        PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
        // etc.
      };
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      scrollBehavior: MyCustomScrollBehavior(),
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomeWT(),
    );
  }
}
```

More on [`ScrollBehaviors`](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/default-desktop-scrollbars).

**Code after migration:**

```dart
// Only manually add a `Scrollbar` when not on desktop platforms.
// Or, see other migrations for changing `ScrollBehavior`.
switch (currentPlatform) {
  case TargetPlatform.linux:
  case TargetPlatform.macOS:
  case TargetPlatform.windows:
    return child;
  case TargetPlatform.android:
  case TargetPlatform.fuchsia:
  case TargetPlatform.iOS:
    return Scrollbar(
      controller: controller,
      child: child;
    );
}
```

Check more about [migration-guide](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/default-desktop-scrollbars#migration-guide) and  [Custom scrollbehavior](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/default-desktop-scrollbars#setting-a-custom-scrollbehavior-for-your-application).

Answer (score 2):

Try below code and Wrap your Widget inside `SizedBox` or `Container` give it width and height

```
body:SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text('Add below or above other widgets'),
            SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Text(' lis sdf sd fsd fsdf ifje fsiduhf iushdf sdf '),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: Text(
                            ' lis sdf sd fsd fsdf ifje fsiduhf iushdf sdf '),
                      ),
                      Text(' lis sdf sd fsd fsdf ifje fsiduhf iushdf sdf ')
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Text('Add below or above other widgets'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Result Screen-> [image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Buy why should I ditch the Column and add a SizedBox? I am planning to add more items to the outer column.

Comment: @Hammerhead check my updated answer, when we horizontally scroll items that time we need to set the width of that widget using `Container` or `SizedBox` **OR** you dont need to used `Container` or `SizedBox` its also working

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the provided Custom Class to enable scrolling via click-and-drag or mouse wheel, allowing you to easily navigate through the content (in Flutter web also).

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      scrollBehavior: MyCustomScrollBehavior(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: theme(),
      home: ChannelInfoScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class MyCustomScrollBehavior extends MaterialScrollBehavior {
  @override
  Set<PointerDeviceKind> get dragDevices => {
        PointerDeviceKind.touch,
        PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
        PointerDeviceKind.stylus,
        PointerDeviceKind.unknown,
      };
}
```